# How to run psutil inside a docker container?

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to monitor the CPU and Memory of my docker container from within my python application . I am planning to use psutil for this job. I have read on other forums that the `/proc` can be changed in psutil.

```
import psutil
psutil.PROCFS_PATH = 'proc/self'
psutil.cpu_percent()
```

This gives me the following error:

```
 File "app.py", line 22, in <module>
 web-vote-app_1  |     r = psutil.cpu_percent()
 web-vote-app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil       /__init__.py", line 1773, in cpu_percent
 web-vote-app_1  |     _last_cpu_times = cpu_times()
 web-vote-app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 1645, in cpu_times
 web-vote-app_1  |     return _psplatform.cpu_times() 
 web-vote-app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/_pslinux.py", line 544, in cpu_times
 web-vote-app_1  |     fields = [float(x) / CLOCK_TICKS for x in fields]
 web-vote-app_1  | ValueError: could not convert string to float: (python)
 web-result_1    |  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5002/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 swarmmicroservicedemov1_web-vote-app_1 exited with code 1
```

Can anyone tell me if its possible to get the same information about the container instead of the host, if so. how ? Thanks

Comment: Its not *my* string, its the filesystem given by the filesystem . I want to know the exact filesystem proc location so that I can monitor the container metrics and not the host system metrics

Comment: You have at least 22 lines in app.py, can you please show all of them?

Comment: Hello, I can show you all of it but I am certain this isnt related to what is in the app. its more to do with the linux file system and its cgroups. psutil by default extracts information from '/proc' which will give me host level metrics but I would like to find out the container level metrics,  so where can I find that .

Comment: Unless you mounted the host /proc there, I don't think that's correct. But then again, I've not ran psutil within a container

Comment: hey, it works when I mount '/proc' which gives me host stats, what I want is the container stats, any idea how? or anyone you know who would know of ? any help will be greatly appreciated . thanks !

Comment: You only get the host if you mount... Don't mount, you get the container...

Comment: @cricket_007, from my experience, the CPU usage that the container sees is the same of the host; regardless the container has its own /proc/ (install and see an `htop` inside a container and you will see the cpu activity (percents) that correspond to the host).

Comment: oh I see. but then, when you do docker stats, we see different cpu percentages for each of them, so it means they have their on cpu usage and stats for it right ?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you changing the default `/proc/` path?

This just works:

```
import psutil
psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
```

Each container has already mounted it's /proc information properly. So psutil can work without mounting any extra.

---

Edit: See it working

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2

RUN pip install psutil

CMD sh -c 'while true; do python -c "import psutil; print psutil.cpu_percent()"; sleep 0.5; done'
```

Build and run:

```
docker build . -t psutil-test && docker run -it psutil-test
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1/3 : FROM python:2
 ---> 2e9467da064d
Step 2/3 : RUN pip install psutil
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bdb07a51b12b
Step 3/3 : CMD sh -c 'while true; do python -c "import psutil; print psutil.cpu_percent()"; sleep 0.5; done'
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 028f88f8844c
Successfully built 028f88f8844c
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
```

Comment: Are you certain of this ?

Comment: I've added `interval=1` to get more realistic cpu usage.

Comment: According to the [source](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/psutil/_pslinux.py#L391), on linux (= in docker), it uses /proc/meminfo for getting memory statistics. This is not per cgroup but for the host: https://ops.tips/blog/why-top-inside-container-wrong-memory/

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is accurate. As mentioned in the comment by Jan - it reports host memory.

Comment: @shaunakde this question and answer is about CPU. Memory is a completely different challenge for checking inside containers.